# Is the initialisation of namespace-scope static storage duration variables thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c++20

The initialisation rules for namespace-scope static storage duration objects are described [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start). I chose the paragraph about inline variables as an example, but the problem is identical for non-inline variables. It says:

*"It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-block inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of that variable. It is implementation-defined in which threads and at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs."*

This does not seem to guarantee that the initialisation will be performed by exactly one thread, and if that's not the case, it says nothing about how those initialisations are synchronised with respect to each other.

I can imagine the following scenario: the control in thread A reaches the first odr-use of a global inline variable `x`. At that point, the initialisation of `x` begins in thread A. Now, after the initialisation of `x` has begun in thread A, but before it has completed, thread B reaches the first odr-use of `x`. Since `x` is still in the process of being initialised, it is considered uninitialised, and therefore thread B may begin to initialise it as well, causing a data race.

Compare the quotation above with the one about the initialisation of block variables with static storage duration described [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl). It says:

*"Dynamic initialization of a block variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. [...] **If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.**"*

Why is this worded so differently? It seems to be much more explicit about the safety of the initialisation in a concurrent context.

Maybe the answers to my questions are obvious from the context - I don't know that, which is why I'm asking the question. I'd really like to know what guarantees the standard provides, regardless of what I can expect from compiler implementations.

Answer (score 1):

> This does not seem to guarantee that the initialisation will be performed by exactly one thread

"happens before any non-initialization odr-use of that variable" is all the standard needs to say. In the C++ memory model. "Strongly happens before" means that all visible side-effects of the the thing will be seen by any subsequent users of it.

You can't have a data race on something that "strongly happens before" your access of a thing. Indeed, the definition of "data race" is [explicitly predicated on *not* having a "happens before" relationship](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races#21):

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions,
> at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other